restore influxdb database from previous installation on other SSD
I had an influxdb (v1.8) server running properly for 2,5 years on a raspberry pi 4, with an SSD.
Unfortunately, after a power cut my raspberry do not start anymore.
Now, I have inserted a pi image on a SD Card, booted from it, and now I can see the 2 partitions of my former SSD installation, boot and rootfs.
So, I guess the issue comes from a corrupted boot partition,as the SSD seems working fine, mounted on ~/media/boot and ~/media/rootfs
Anyway, I have installed influxdb on the SD card, and I am searching for a way to connect it to my datas on the SSD. Is it possible?
I see influxdb installation under ~/media/rootfs/var/lib/influxdb/* on my SSD. As I guess, this should contain my former database, or am I wrong?
I have tried to tweak /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf
[meta] dir, [data] dir, wal-dir, changing pathes to point to the SSD, but no way, influx service does not start anymore.
So, where stand my datas, and how could I connect to/backup them ?
Thanks for any help
Claude
